# Is there an (online) SRD for Cthulhu d20?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu-d20

As the title says: **Is there an (online) SRD for Cthulhu d20?** If so, where can we find it?

Note that a definite "no", supported by some factual resource, is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The below is written on **wizards.com** under the **[d20 System Trademark FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=d20/srdfaq/20040123b)**:

> Q: What parts of Call of Cthulhu and Wheel of Time are Open Game Content?
>
> A: No part of these games is Open Game Content.

This is a definite no.

However, bits of relevant open content can be gathered from a number of places:

- Sanity rules from the [d20srd.org](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/sanity.htm) wiki, as Jonn_Underwood already put it.
- Certain monsters from the Pathfinder SRD wiki, eg. the [Star-Spawn of Chtulhu](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/star-spawn-of-cthulhu) or [Gnoph-Keh](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/gnoph-keh).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, no part of *Call of Cthulhu d20* was released under OGL, therefore, no official SRD exists.

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu_%28role-playing_game%29#D20_Call_of_Cthulhu),

> The d20 version of the game is no longer supported by Wizards as per their contract with Chaosium. Chaosium included d20 stats as an appendix in three releases, but have since dropped the "dual stat" idea.

That is the most relevant official text on the topic that I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

There are sanity rules for a Call of Cthulhu themed campaign which can be found [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/sanity.htm).

I was planning on a Call of Cthulhu campaign and those are the only things I found so they may not have more then that. I hope this helps.